# Show animation speed in pixels per second

Tags: animation

Is it possible to view the speed of a movement in Blender? In other animation software it is usually possible to see how many pixels per second an object is moving at. This is very useful when you need to achieve constant speed between different parts of an animation. Can Blender show the speed of an animation in either pixels or Blender units? I'm aware of the graph editor, but it's only showing me a value graph and I would like to see a speed graph.

Comment: While I can't think of a way for Blender to output a numerical value for speed in pixels, you can use the Vector render pass to see the speed of individual pixels.